# Get the info of a script tag of html with jsoup in android

Tags: jsoup

I had asked this question but I got no answer so I'm asking it again. Consider a script tag of a html like this:

```
<script id="ld" type="application/ld+json>"@type": "Recipe","name": "Some Name","datePublished": "7-26-2018 ","description": "Some Desc"</script>
```

How can I extract "Some Name" or "Some Desc" values using jsoup codes in android?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is not able to get these values because what you have there is JSON and Jsoup can't parse JSON. 
I've had the idea of getting content of `<script>` using Jsoup and then parsing it using other library, but Jsoup even breaks this content so it's useless in your case. Broken body of script tag:

```
 <script id="ld" type="application/ld+json> " @type":="" "Recipe","name":=""
```